# Macro error 1004 when pasting but only on other computers

Tags: excel, runtime-error, paste, vba

My macro's work just fine on my (citrix) workpost, but on other workposts I get a 1004 error, and I don't understand why.

It concerns a series of 18 macro's that copy/paste shapes from one (source) sheet to another (destination) sheet, deleting the former shape from the destination sheet before copy/pasting the next one.

Goal is to guide the user through 18 infoscreens (=rectangular shapes with text in it)... he moves through the infoscreens by clicking on a button (in the infoscreen) that is linked to the macro's

The error always occurs on the line that should paste the shape to the destination sheet.

Strangely the 1004 error does not always occur in the same macro, sometimes I manage to get through several screens, sometimes it blocks at the first one.

All help or suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Macro text:

> ```
>    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
>    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TFS9")).Select
>    Selection.Delete
>    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TFS9TEL")).Select
>    Selection.Delete
>    Sheets("Tour FIP Shop").Visible = True
>    Sheets("Tour FIP Shop").Select
>    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TFS10")).Select
>    Selection.Copy
>    Sheets("FIP Shop").Select
>    Range("e18").Select
>    ActiveSheet.Paste
>    Application.CutCopyMode = False
>    Sheets("Tour FIP Shop").Select
>    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TFS10TEL")).Select
>    Selection.Copy
>    Sheets("FIP Shop").Select
>    Range("Q41").Select
>    ActiveSheet.Paste
>    Application.CutCopyMode = False
>    Sheets("Tour FIP Shop").Select
>    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
>    Sheets("FIP Shop").Select
>    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
>    Application.CutCopyMode = False
>    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
> ```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please, show a minimal example of your code so we can look for what may be the reason of your problem.

Comment: @vincent: i added the macro text

Comment: Nice. Now, you should add tags, at least one specifying the language you use (VBA I think ?) so people competent in that language are more likely to see (and hence answer) your question.

Comment: @Vincent, done, thx!

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a similar problem. For me, it was helpful to remove the 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False' statement. This statement seems to crash Excel sometimes when running within a CITRIX environment.